# Is it acceptable for all ".h" files import "macros.h" to set verbosity with preprocessing directives

Tags: c++

As described in the title, the question is if it considered a good practice to set a code's verbosity by making all ".h" files import one single ".h" file where preprocessing directives are defined? e.g.

macros.h contains

```
#ifndef VERBOSE
#define VERBOSE true
#endif
```

then functions1.h could be

```
#include "../macros/macros.h"

void eatBurguers(int i){
    if (VERBOSE) {
        printf("Today I ate %d burguers, yum!", i);
    }
}
```

And functions2.h could be

```
#include "../macros/macros.h"
#include <vector>

void preallocateVector(std::vector<int> &v){
    if (VERBOSE) {
        printf("About to resize a vector");
    }   
    v.resize(100);
    if (VERBOSE) {
        printf("A vector has just been resized");
    }   
}
```

Besides saving us the time that it would take to just add the macro at each ".h" file, it occurs to me that it could be less untidy.

EDIT: indeed answers and comments addressed how the answer depends on the specifics of each project, which I understand somehow means that there is nothing inherently wrong in the practice previously described.

More info: the present use-case is a Scientific Computing application which moved the definition of verbosity a step prior to compilation in order to allow some 'smart compiler' to erase the ifs, so producing a final app that allows verbose output is not necessary and explicitly checking for the definition in each print was considered to decrease readability.

EDIT2: after Chris' answer, indeed there was a 'better' method.

Comment: why not? Consider the alternative of setting preprocessor symbols globally via argument to the compiler, and `#ifdef VERBOSE` instead of `if (VERBOSE)`. This is largely opinion based

Comment: *" is it considered a good practice"* - I hope you are interested in in knowing what are implications of doing something like that instead of a dogmatic "good practice" to follow. Because good practices become bad practices when they are used outside their sphere of benefit and code becomes convoluted to "follow best practices".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Littering code with `if`s or `#if defined` is madness and makes a codebase difficult to read and work with.

If you are going to have a common header to define macros, then make the expansion of the macros be what you actually want (instead of making them only be a condition that must be checked.)  I'm not a big fan of macros in code to do this in general but if you're going to do it, at least put all the conditional code in a single place.

That is, if you have macros.h, do something like this:

```
#if defined(VERBOSE)
#define PRINTF_DBG printf
#else
#define PRINTF_DBG(...) 
#endif
```

Then in your files that use it, just call `PRINTF_DBG` *without any testing at all* and it'll either expand to `printf(<args>)` or will simply *go away*.

```
void preallocateVector(std::vector<int> &v){
    PRINTF_DBG("About to resize a vector");

    v.resize(100);

    PRINTF_DBG("A vector has just been resized");
}
```

The code is *much* cleaner and less noisy.

Compare the results of the preprocessor with and without VERBOSE defined:
https://godbolt.org/z/hG33MYvr3

Comment: I have accepted this as an answer because (1) it improves readibility, (2) it has a quantitative approach, and (3) it appears to remove the need for the compiler to be 'smart'.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider it bad practice using `if` with a condition that is a sole preprocessor macros.

As you are using a preprocessor macro to decide if you want verbose output or not, I'd rather use conditional compilation like this:

```
void preallocateVector(std::vector<int> &v){
#if VERBOSE == 1
        printf("About to resize a vector");
#endif

    v.resize(100);

#if VERBOSE == 1
        printf("A vector has just been resized");
#endif
}
```

On the other hand if you want to switch on/off verbosity during runtime and only in this case, then you may want something like this:

```
...
bool verbose_mode;

// set verbose_mode to true or false depending on whatever condition during runtime

void preallocateVector(std::vector<int> &v){
    if (verbose_mode) {
        printf("About to resize a vector");
    }   
    v.resize(100);
    if (verbose_mode) {
        printf("A vector has just been resized");
    }   
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you suggest changing the verbosity from a macro-defined value to a global variable. Would the setting of this global variable in this "macro.h" imported file be a good practice then? Regarding your first suggestion, please note that the only motivation I find not to do it is to "increase readability" (albeit not much).

Comment: The only thing I suggest is doing everything with the preprocessor _if and only if_ you solely want to specifiy verbosity during the compilation process and never during runtime.